# How to filter rows and select desire columns from client side

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Consider this scenario:

I have a reference data that I write service to return this to my clients.In my program I use  this data in different types.

I want to get exactly what I want from database from client and in dynamic manner.

I want to use such this code:

```
public List<TResult> FindAll<T, TResult>(Func<T, bool> exp, Func<T, TResult> selector, int PageSize) where TResult : class
{        
}
```

the problem is I can't declare my service interface as generic and I can't use that code this way:

```
public List<TResult> FindAll<Order, TResult>(Func<Order, bool> exp, Func<Order, TResult> selector, int PageSize) where TResult : class
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        return dc.Orders.Where(exp).Select<Order, TResult>(selector).ToList<TResult>();
    }
}
```

Because:

1. Order in function act as parameter not Order class.
2. my TResult is not declared in service

How I can do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: EF or LINQ to SQL? Choose one.

Comment: Can you write answer for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make your method generic, you cannot pass delegate as parameter and you probably cannot pass expression tree as parameter as well because I think it is by default not serializable. You should use some API which already do this for you - check [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) or [Expression Tree Serialization](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization).